# Unable to pass php variables into html Dialog Popup Box

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the code below with a popup dialog box. For some reason, the dialog box isn't display the text passed inside the `<a>` tag where `data-soldusers=\"$soldUsersstr\"`. I am using the base64_encode to encode the string which contains `<select><option>` html tag. And then pass it to popup dialog of using codeiginter framework.

```
$soldUsersstr=base64_encode($soldUsersstr);

echo "<p><div class=\"user-ads-action\"><a class=\"btn btn-info btn-xs\"  data-toggle=\"modal\"   href=\"#markSoldAds\"   data-soldusers=\"$soldUsersstr\"  $str> <i class=\"fa fa-mail-forward\"></i>".$this->lang->line('MarkSold')." </a></div></p>";

<div   id="divSoldUser" name="divSoldUser"  class="center">

</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#markSoldAds').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        $("#postID").val($(event.relatedTarget).data('id'));
         $("#divSoldUser").html(jsbase64_decode($(event.relatedTarget).data('soldusers')));
    });
});



function jsbase64_decode(data) {

          var b64 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
          var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
            ac = 0,
            dec = '',
            tmp_arr = [];

          if (!data) {
            return data;
          }

          data += '';

          do { // unpack four hexets into three octets using index points in b64
            h1 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
            h2 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
            h3 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
            h4 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));

            bits = h1 << 18 | h2 << 12 | h3 << 6 | h4;

            o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff;
            o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff;
            o3 = bits & 0xff;

            if (h3 == 64) {
              tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1);
            } else if (h4 == 64) {
              tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2);
            } else {
              tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2, o3);
            }
          } while (i < data.length);

          dec = tmp_arr.join('');

          return dec.replace(/\0+$/, '');
        }
```

Any idea why my dialog box isn't displaying any text at all?

Comment: Actually I am using bootstrap framework with codeigniter. I guess I am using bootsctrap popup. Any help??